# Excel VBA: coerce information into comma separated strings

Tags: excel, vba, string, csv, coerce

I have two excel worksheets ("Sheet1" and "Sheet2"). Sheet2 contains rawdata that I want to group and present in "Sheet1" based on ID. That is, I want to coerce 'FEED' and 'NUMB' based on ID, and store 'FEED' and 'NUMB' as comma separated strings (see example data below).

This procedure needs to be dynamic, i.e. if I enter new data into Sheet2, the information presented in Sheet1 is updated automatically.

Note that I'd like to do this using VBA, in which I am an absolute beginner (Microsoft Excel 2019 and **non-english**). I've been trying to do this in reverse (i.e. splitting data stored according to Sheet1 to Sheet2) using VBA, however I've been unsuccessfull in my trials. I generally do not prefer working in Excel although current circumstances forces my hand at this

```
Sheet2

| Group | ID    | FEED  | NUMB |
|:-----:|:-----:|:-----:|:----:|
| B     | B1    | C1    | 1    |
| B     | B2    | L3    | 43   |
| B     | B3    | K12   | 101  |
| B     | B1    | G1    | 86   |
| B     | B3    | H2    | 109  |
| C     | C1    | L3    | 23   |
| C     | C2    | G1    | 24   |
| C     | C1    | L4    | 54   |
| C     | C1    | K8    | 56   |

Sheet1

| Group | ID | FEED     | NUMB     |
|:-----:|:--:|:--------:|:--------:|
| B     | B1 | C1,G1    | 1,86     |
| B     | B2 | L3       | 43       |
| B     | B3 | K12,H2   | 101,109  |
| C     | C1 | L3,L4,K8 | 23,54,56 |
| C     | C2 | G1       | 24       |
```

Comment: If you are `an absolute beginner` with VBA, you might consider using the existing `=TEXTJOIN()` Function and avoid VBA entirely?  See https://www.howtoexcel.org/formulas/how-to-conditionally-concatenate-a-range-formula/.

Comment: If this is a task and not just a learning tool for VBA, consider using Power Query (available in Windows Excel 2010+ and O365) with it's built-in `GroupBy` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It returns starting from "O1". It can return anywhere you need:

```
Sub TestProcessCommaSep()
 'It needs a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime'
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrFin, arrInt
 Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary, i As Long, k As Long
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
 lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 
 arr = sh.Range("A2:D" & lastR).value   'put the range to be processed in an array
 ReDim arrFin(1 To 4, 1 To UBound(arr)) 'redim the final array to make space for maximum
 
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr) 'iterate between arr elements
    If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1) & "|" & arr(i, 2)) Then 'if the key does not exist:
        dict.Add arr(i, 1) & "|" & arr(i, 2), arr(i, 3) & "|" & arr(i, 4) 'it is created
    Else
        'add to the existing key the values in columns 3 and 4:
        arrInt = Split(dict((arr(i, 1) & "|" & arr(i, 2))), "|")
        dict(arr(i, 1) & "|" & arr(i, 2)) = arrInt(0) & "," & arr(i, 3) & "|" & arrInt(1) & "," & arr(i, 4)
    End If
 Next i
 'fill the final array:
 For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
    k = k + 1
    arrFin(1, k) = Split(dict.Keys(i), "|")(0)
    arrFin(2, k) = Split(dict.Keys(i), "|")(1)
    arrFin(3, k) = Split(dict.items(i), "|")(0)
    arrFin(4, k) = Split(dict.items(i), "|")(1)
 Next
 ReDim Preserve arrFin(1 To 4, 1 To k) 'keep only the elements keeping values
 'Put the header, dropping the array elements at once:
 With sh.Range("O1")
    .Resize(1, 4).value = sh.Range("A1:D1").value
    With .Offset(1).Resize(k, 4)
        .value = Application.Transpose(arrFin)
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
 End With
End Sub
```

If you do not know how to add the necessary reference, please firstly run the next code, which will automatically add it. Save the workbook after that...

```
Sub addScrRunTimeRef()
  'Adding a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime':
  'In case of error ('Programmatic access to Visual Basic Project not trusted'):
  'Options->Trust Center->Trust Center Settings->Macro Settings->Developer Macro Settings->
  '         check "Trust access to the VBA project object model"
  Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. This code does exactly what I'm looking for. Note that I had to add "End Sub" at the last line of the code in order to get it to work.

Comment: @user09034: Ups... I missed it when copied. Glad I could help. I will correct it now.